# Ios app is still installing in the device even after removing udid from the provision profile

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios7

First i added the udid of device and made a build and it got installed in my device . After that i removed the udid from the provision profile and made a new build it again got installed . Is it a bug from apple? Or do i have to follow any other steps to avoid installation of app in a particular device.

Comment: Did you delete the provisioning profile from the device under Settings->General->Profiles ?

Comment: No i havent removed that . I ll try it now. Thank you